# How to Remove 3d objects which are placed on AR Screen

Tags: android, arcore, android-sdk-manager

I have an AR Screen where I placed some 3d objects. I am using google AR Core with android SDK.

I need to remove those objects from the scene on clicking of a clear button.

I was able to remove the last placed object. But the other objects were not removing.

This is the code i am using.

```
if (newAnchor != null) {
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(newAnchor);
            newAnchor.getAnchor().detach();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can detach android model from scene form using below code

```
 List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getChildren());
        for (Node node : children) {
            if (node instanceof AnchorNode) {
                if (((AnchorNode) node).getAnchor() != null) {
                    ((AnchorNode) node).getAnchor().detach();
                }
            }
            if (!(node instanceof Camera) && !(node instanceof Sun)) {
                node.setParent(null);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cleanup the scene, you can do the following:

```
arSceneView.getScene().callOnHierarchy(node -> {
  node.setParent(null);
  if (node instanceof AnchorNode) {
    ((AnchorNode) node).getAnchor().detach();
  }
}
```

Comment: So, Can't I remove the 3d objects placed on the scene one by one. I want to remove the objects whenever they are double tapped

Comment: Yes you definitely can do that, but you'll have to keep track of the nodes you want to remove.

Comment: Yes. so do we need to store those nodes in a list before adding them ? And then later remove them based on index ?

Comment: It really depends on how you're handling those clicks and if you can reference a node from a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if a user has tapped on a particular node like this - in this example the check is to see if the hit node is an 'Andy' renderable, i.e. the default example renderable with Sceneform:

```js
private void handleOnTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"handleOnTouch");
        // First call ArFragment's listener to handle TransformableNodes.
        arFragment.onPeekTouch(hitTestResult, motionEvent);

        // Check for touching a Sceneform node
        if (hitTestResult.getNode() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"handleOnTouch hitTestResult.getNode() != null");
            Node hitNode = hitTestResult.getNode();

            if (hitNode.getRenderable() == andyRenderable) {
                //DO whatever you need to here...

            }
            return;
```

And you can delete a node like this:

```js
private void removeAnchorNode(AnchorNode nodeToremove) {
        //Remove an anchor node
        if (nodeToremove != null) {
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(nodeToremove);
            anchorNodeList.remove(nodeToremove);
            nodeToremove.getAnchor().detach();
            nodeToremove.setParent(null);
            nodeToremove = null;
        } else {
            //Handle error case here
        }
    }
```

Full code available here: https://github.com/mickod/LineView - the above are edited excerpts.